# check if a DataGridView has a DataSource

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

i have a module that imports an `Excel File` and display its contents in a `DataGridView Object`. At the same time, i have a module that will export the contents of a `DataGridView Object`'s `DataSource as a DataTable` to an `Excel File`.

how can i check if a DataGridView has a DataSource by not doing a `if(dataGridView1.Rows.Count == 0){}`Condition.

this is because i have noticed that even if a user imports or open an empty `Excel File` the `DataGridView Object` still display a single `Column`.

this is why i want to try and check if a `DataGridView Object` has a `DataSource`

im looking for a code something like

```
if(dataGridView1.DataSource == true)
{
   // do something is DataSource if found or is bound
} 
else
{ 
   //do something is DataSource is not found or is not bound 
}
```

EDIT -- for now i am using this code to filter empty DataSources:

assuming that:

```
var dtList = new Dictionary<string, DataTable>() {
    { "dataGridView1", (DataTable) (dataGridView1.DataSource) },
    { "dataGridView2", (DataTable) (dataGridView2.DataSource) },
    { "dataGridView3", (DataTable) (dataGridView3.DataSource) },
    { "dataGridView4", (DataTable) (dataGridView4.DataSource) }
};
```

and that `dataGridView1` and `dataGridView3` has no `DataSource` or the `DataGridView Object` is empty. i run the code below to filter and remove those 2 empty `DataTable`:

```
//Filter and Remove empty DataTable(s)
var remList = new List<string>();

    foreach(var dt in dtList) {
        try {
            var dump = dt.Value.GetType().ToString();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            remList.Add(dt.Key);
        }
    }

    foreach(var rem in remList) {
        dtList.Remove(rem);
    }
```

with this code, i am able to filter out all other empty `DataTable` from the `dtList Object`. But of course, i am seeking for a better formula than this. so yeah, hope i can get some tips and codes. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest write code to validate empty rows in the `DataGridView` to avoid exporting empty rows.

You could look for validating `DataSource` to *null*, but I seriously doubt how this is different from validating rows count.

Since you mentioned you see an empty row being added when importing excel, you could avoid exporting empty datagridview to excel by doing this validation.

```
DataTable source = dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
var emptyrows = source.AsEnumerable()
                       .All(r=> r.ItemArray.All(x=> x == DBNull.Value));

if(!emptyrows)
{
   //export
}
```

Comment: yes correct, you could modify to normal looping (if want)

Answer (score 0):

If the DataSource is not yet assigend it will be `null` So you can check them like the following:

```
if(dataGridView1.DataSource == null)
{
   // do something there is no assigned Datasource
} 
else
{ 
   //do something with the DataSource
}
```

Comment: yes but how can i check if a `DataTable` / `DataSource` is while within the `Dictionary Object` ? because my code first compiles all the `DataGridView Object`'s `DataSource` into one `List<DataTable> Object` then passes the `List Object` to the `Method` that validates and filters empty `DataTables` from the `List Object`